# How to tackle server-side input validation using Relay?

Tags: relayjs

I have the following GraphQL operation that works:

**GraphQL Mutation:**

```
mutation CreateUserMutation ($input: CreateUserInput!) {
  createUser(input: $input) {
    clientMutationId
    userEdge {
      node {
        email
        username
      }
    },
    validationErrors {
      id
      email
    }
  }
}
```

**GraphQL mutation response:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "createUser": {
      "clientMutationId": "112",
      "userEdge": {
        "node": {
          "email": "prasath112@example.com",
          "username": "soosap112"
        }
      },
      "validationErrors": {
        "id": "create-user-validation-errors",
        "email": [
          "Email looks not so good."
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So far so good, my GraphQL response's `validationErrors` is an object of key-value pairs, where the *value* is always an array of input validation error messages from the server w/ respect to a particular input field (i.e. `{'email': ['email is taken', 'email is on blacklist']`}).

Next step (and this is where I need help) - *how to consume that data in the Relay client store*? In other words, *what to do to have the validationErrors available in my component as `this.props.validationErrors`*?

**CreateUserMutation.js**

```js
import Relay from 'react-relay';

export class CreateUserMutation extends Relay.Mutation {
  getMutation() {
    return Relay.QL`
      mutation {
        createUser
      }
    `;
  }

  getVariables() {
    return {
      email: this.props.email,
      username: this.props.username,
      password: this.props.password,
    };
  }

  getFatQuery() {
    return Relay.QL`
      fragment on CreateUserPayload @relay(pattern: true) {
        userEdge,
        validationErrors,
        viewer { userConnection }
      }
    `;
  }

  getConfigs() {
    return [
      {
        type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
        fieldIDs: {
          validationErrors: 'create-user-validation-errors',
        },
      },
      {
        type: 'RANGE_ADD',
        parentName: 'viewer',
        parentID: this.props.viewer.id,
        connectionName: 'userConnection',
        edgeName: 'userEdge',
        rangeBehaviors: {
          // When the ships connection is not under the influence
          // of any call, append the ship to the end of the connection
          '': 'append',
          // Prepend the ship, wherever the connection is sorted by age
          // 'orderby(newest)': 'prepend',
        },
      },
    ];
  }
}
```

Here is my attempt: First of all I am able to consume *user edges* into my Relay client store by using the *getConfigs* `RANGE_ADD`. Since my `validationErrors` object does not implement the connection model, the `FIELDS_CHANGE` seemed to be the only reasonable type in my case. I am trying to mock the **dataID** that Relay seems to require to populate the client store using 'create-user-validation-errors' as a unique id.

Here is a snippet from my React component to make the example complete.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    limit: React.PropTypes.number,
    viewer: React.PropTypes.object,
    validationErrors: React.PropTypes.object,
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    limit: 5,
    validationErrors: {
      id: 'create-user-validation-errors',
    },
  };

  handleUserSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    Relay.Store.commitUpdate(
      new CreateUserMutation({
        email: this.refs.newEmail.value,
        username: this.refs.newUsername.value,
        password: this.refs.newPassword.value,
        viewer: this.props.viewer,
      })
    );
  };
```

---

- How do I consume a non-connection model based piece of information from a GraphQL response in a React component using Relay? Minimum working example would be awesome.
- Do you know of a better way of doing server-side input validation using GraphQL and Relay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mutation either succeeds or fails. I usually design the client-side mutation's fat query and configs, keeping the success case in mind. To handle failure case, the mutation's callback functions are sufficient.

### How do I consume a non-connection model based piece of information from a GraphQL response in a React component using Relay?

There are **two ways** that I know of.

**1) Using `FIELDS_CHANGE` type in `getConfigs` function of client-side mutation code:** When we need to update data in Relay store in response to the mutation's result, this is usually used. The code looks like the following:

```
getFatQuery() {
  return Relay.QL`
    fragment on CreateUserPayload {
      ...
      ...
      viewer { 
        userCount,
      }
    }
  `;
}

getConfigs() {
  return [
    {
      type: 'FIELDS_CHANGE',
      fieldIDs: {
        viewer: this.props.viewer.id,
      },
    },
    ...
    ...
  ];
}
```

In your case, if you want to update `validationErrors` as part of the Relay store, pass it as a prop and have `validationErrors: this.props.validationErrors.id`.

**2) Using mutation's callback functions:** When we just need some information that shouldn't affect the data in Relay store, this is a good option. The code looks like below:

```
const mutation = new CreateUserMutation({
  email: this.state.email,
  username: this.state.username,
  password: this.state.password,
  viewer: this.props.viewer,
});
const onSuccess = (response) => {
  // If you have both successful data update and some other extra info, you
  // can have, say `response.warnings`. The server sends `warnings` in the
  // response object.
};
const onFailure = (transaction) => {
  // This is the most appropriate place for dealing with errors.
  var error = transaction.getError();
  // Get the errors!
};
Relay.Store.commitUpdate(mutation, {onSuccess, onFailure});
```

### Do you know of a better way of doing server-side input validation using GraphQL and Relay?

The elementary input validation supported by GraphQL and Relay are currently limited to using `GraphQLNonNull` and the intended types, for example, `names: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)`. So, if we pass an integer for name, the mutation will fail and appropriate error message will be provided.

For other types of validation, `mutateAndGetPayload` function in server-side mutation is a good place, where we can apply our own logic.

[Konstantin Tarkus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82686/konstantin-tarkus) has [an excellent article](https://medium.com/@tarkus/validation-and-user-errors-in-graphql-mutations-39ca79cd00bf#.w78pch799) on input validation in GraphQL mutations.

Comment: Hey there, this is exactly what I was looking for - thanks for the clarification. I have read the cited article. Tarkus distinguishes between system level errors and app level errors. Whereas **system level errors** can be handled well in the `onFailure` callback, **app level errors** shall be handled in the `mutateAndGetPayload` - that's what I got out of it.

Comment: @soosap Found a npm module [graphql-errors](https://github.com/kadirahq/graphql-errors) that masks GraphQL _system level_ errors for the client. I haven't used it myself. Thought you may be interested in.

Comment: Does `transaction.getError()` return an object?

Comment: @maxwell: Yes, `transaction.getError()` returns an object like `{"source":{"data":{"mutation_name":null},"errors":[{"message":"error_message_thrown_in_server","locations":[{"line":1,"column":68}]}]}}`

Comment: reading up https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/777 it seems that @soosap solution was better off, he could use the query config REQUIRED_CHILDREN to then interact with the response payload